# AJAX - database connection

Tags: php, ajax, database

What I was wondering is the following:
When you call a script, lets call it makePage.php, clicking on a button and thus making an AJAX-request. Do I have to establish a new database connection? Even if I already established a connection to load in the page where the button is rendered on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the page you call with AJAX (more or less) acts like a page visited by a browser. there is no hidden magic going on, it's an independent page you load.

therefore you also have to care about database connections if you need them.

Comment: Thank you, I just needed to verify this ^^

Comment: @Abayob glad that I could help you. Please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: (I had to wait 3 more minutes before I could xD)

Answer (score 0):

Ajax always loads results only. So you need to establish a connection everytime to db for your ajax file.